# hf energy in Schrödinger Wave Equation

Tags: schroedinger-equation

I don't underand how the Planck-Einstein energy, hf, is used in the Schrödinger Wave Equation (SWE). It appears that hf is equated to the TOTAL ENERGY term for the matter particle (I.e hf =. kinetic energy + potential energy). But outside of the SWE topic I can only find hf being applicable to photon energy, I can't a reference for it being relevant to the energy of a particle with rest mass.

So my questions are:
1. Am I correct in interpreting the use of hf in the SWE as hf = total energy = kinetic energy + potential energy?
2 If so, is this equality demonstrated by data/theory outside of the SWE development? Or was the equality first postulated during the development of the SWE and then validated by the SWE solutions agreeing with experimental data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a state of definite energy, $H\psi = E\psi$. The Schrödinger equation says that $H\psi = i\hbar (\partial \psi / \partial t)$, so substituting we get

$$E\psi = i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}$$

which is solved by a function of the form $\psi \sim e^{-i\omega t}$, and plugging into the equation says that

$$E = \hbar \omega$$

This is a completely general analysis: *any* definite energy state has a wavefunction that goes as $\exp(-iEt/\hbar)$. If you make your theory relativistic, for example, then $E$ includes the rest mass of your particle. But in general it is the total energy for any state.

Comment: Javier, can you specifically answer question 1 and 2, using the terms in the questions?

Comment: @SPG: I specifically say that $E$ is always is the total energy. And as for your second question, I've shown that the Schrödinger equation in its most general form implies that $E=\hbar\omega$, and of course the equation is completely validated by experiment. The Planck equation came about earlier, but Schrödinger formalized the theory.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Javier. I know that E in the SWE is the total energy. My question #1 is instead asking about hf and whether hf is the total energy. Are you saying that hf is indeed total energy i.e. K.E. + P.E. ?  Then  for #2: are you saying that the origin of E = hf being applicable to particles first came during the development of the SWE I.e. that the extension of its applicability, from photons to electrons, was first realized during development of the SWE?

Comment: @SPG: You can't really divide energy into kinetic and potential in quantum mechanics. You can do that to build your Hamiltonian, but in the end you just have total energy. And I'm not completely clear on the history, but as far as I know people realized matter particles (e.g. electrons) behaved as waves before Schrödinger came along. He postulated the wave equation for "matter waves", and Born came up with the probability interpretation.